# Prove the following equation for the angle between two vectors.

Tags: matrices, transformation

I'm currently reviewing coordinate and matrix transformations for a physics class. In one of the questions, I am asked to prove the following two equations.

Equation 1
\begin{equation}
cos^2(\alpha)+cos^2(\beta)+cos^2(\gamma)=1
\end{equation}
Equation 2 $$ cos(\theta)=cos(\alpha)cos(\alpha')+cos(\beta)cos(\beta')+cos(\gamma)cos(\gamma') $$

I've proven Eq. 1 using the law of cosines, with help from a separate post here on this site.  I have a hunch that the proof for the second equation will be similar to the first, but I'm lost on where I should start. I've explored the law of cosines with two vectors, but I am either missing something, or it's getting me nowhere.

I'm looking for a push in the right direction.

Thank you!

EDIT: Alpha is the angle from the x-axis to the vector, beta is the angle from the y-axis to the vector, and gamma is the angle from the z-axis to the vector.

Comment: What are these angles supposed to represent? They look like direction cosines, but without context it's hard to be sure. (FYI, the Wikipedia page on [direction cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_cosine) includes a proof of the first relation.)

Comment: @Semiclassical , I apologize. Does my edit help at all? My proof for equation 1 is similar to the proof on Wikipedia.

Comment: It does. I think if you use the characterization in what I linked (i.e. $\cos \theta_k = \frac{\mathbf{v}}{v}\cdot \mathbf{e}_k$ for the angle to the $k$th axis) then the question becomes more straightforward. (Consider the dot product between two unit vectors $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$.)

Comment: Solved. Thank you for your help, @Semiclassical.

Comment: @ Semiclassical If you see anything wrong with the proof I posted below, please let me know. I purposely left out the algebra and a few steps for anyone who stumbles across this problem in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof to Eq. 1 can be found [here](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Direction_cosine)

For Eq. 2:

The dot product of two vectors is defined to be 
$$ \mathbf V \cdot \mathbf W =||\mathbf V|| \cdot ||\mathbf W|| cos(\theta)  $$
Where 
$$\mathbf V =(x,y,z),  \mathbf W=(x',y',z') $$
We see that 
$$ cos(\theta) = \frac {\mathbf V \cdot \mathbf W }{||\mathbf V|| \cdot ||\mathbf W||} = \frac{(x,y,z)\cdot(x',y',z')}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^\frac{1}{2}(x'^2+y'^2+z'^2)^\frac{1}{2}} $$

From the proof for Eq. 1, we see that
$$ cos(\alpha)=x(x^2+y^2+z^2)^\frac{-1}{2} $$
$$ cos(\beta)=y(x^2+y^2+z^2)^\frac{-1}{2} $$
$$ cos(\gamma)=z(x^2+y^2+z^2)^\frac{-1}{2} $$

We can then assume that the same relationship holds true for the primed system. i.e., $$ cos(\alpha')=x'(x'^2+y'^2+z'^2)^\frac{-1}{2} $$
$$ cos(\beta')=y'(x'^2+y'^2+z'^2)^\frac{-1}{2} $$
$$ cos(\gamma')=z'(x'^2+y'^2+z'^2)^\frac{-1}{2} $$

By expanding the equation for $cos(\theta)$ above and substituting the values above, we then prove that 
$$ cos(\theta)=cos(\alpha)cos(\alpha')+cos(\beta)cos(\beta')+cos(\gamma)cos(\gamma') $$

Answer (score 1):

Let u and v be two unit vectors, with direction angles $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ and $\alpha^{\prime}, \beta^{\prime}, \gamma^{\prime}$, and let $\theta$ be the angle between $u$ and $v$.

Then $\displaystyle \cos\theta=\frac{u\cdot v}{|u||v|}=\frac{\cos(\alpha)\cos(\alpha^{\prime})+\cos(\beta)\cos(\beta^{\prime})+\cos(\gamma)\cos(\gamma^{\prime})}{1\cdot1}$.